# Two rows for each element in a query

Tags: sql, firebird

I've got two simple tables in Firebird 2.1:

Invoices:
**`InvocesID, ClientID, .....`**

and

Client: 
**`ClientID, GroupID, Name .......`**

When I select

```
 SELECT   
       I.*   
 FROM 
       INVOICES I  
       LEFT JOIN CLIENT C ON C.ClientId=I.ClientID  
 WHERE 
    C.GroupID = 15  // for instance
```

Then I've got all invoices. How can I get only 2 invoices for each client in `groupid =15`?

Comment: Might need some more clarification as to why you'd expect 2 results for each client. From what you've supplied there could be many invoices to any client. Have you added ClientID to the where clause? `WHERE C.GroupID  = 15 AND I.ClientID = $clientID`

Comment: Upgrade to Firebird 3 and use the window functions like `row_number()`.

Comment: why would you need two random invoices out of many?

Comment: Lex, the Clients have facultative number of invoices, but i'd like to have only two (if any), no more. In my query i receive all invoices for each client. But i'd like to limit the result for each client from the group with id=15

Comment: Arioch, i'd like to have last two invoices not random....

Comment: If you want "last" invoices you have to tell what it means, which column(s) represent "lastness" and should they be minimized or maximized.

Answer (score 1):

The sipmplest (not so optimal solution but working in any Firebird version especially your ancient 2.1) is:

```
SELECT
    I.*
FROM
    CLIENT C
    INNER JOIN INVOICES I ON C.ClientId = I.ClientID AND I.InvocesID >=
    (SELECT FIRST 1 SKIP 1 I2.InvocesID FROM INVOICES I2 WHERE I2.ClientId = I.ClientID ORDER BY I2.InvocesID DESC)
WHERE
    C.GroupID = 15
```

i have assumed that your newest invoice have bigger number.
Also i have changed `left join` to `inner join` as you are interested in invoices. If you also need to return clients with no invoices at all change it to `LEFT JOIN`

If you need not `2` but e.g. `4` invoices simply change `SKIP 1` to `SKIP 3`

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense to directly join with `(select first 2 .... Desc)` instead of using `invoices` table twice

Comment: @ Arioch - no, this limit result set to 2 invoices at all not 2 invoices per client (LATERAL JOIN)

Comment: Of course I wanted to put the condition on C.ClientID=i2.ClientID inside the brackets. But seems that is not possible to do it so, just tried in SQLFiddle

Comment: Livius - that was that! Thx, although i wrote it in a seperate procedure....Robert